# Ext JS 4.1 - how to access cell element in grid

Tags: extjs

I have grid with check boxes. By default some check boxes will be selected based on the data from the database. I used renderer method to create HTML check boxes.

Now user can select new check boxes and submit that data to the server. To submit this data, how can I know a particular check box is checked or not? I mean how to get the particular cell element.

UPDATE:

This is the code i used to add the check box.

```
renderer: function (value, cell) {
                            if(value == 'Y')
                                return '<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" checked="true"/>';
                            else
                                return '<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/>';
                        }
```

Now I need to check all check boxes whether they are checked or not.

I have tried to use below code, but this is giving the value of check box instead it checked or not.

```
store.getAt(1).get(dataIndex);
```

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: You have to show some code. In generic terms, you should be storing the checked state as a field in the model instance itself, and you'd need to iterate over all the records in the store to find out which are checked

Comment: Please show some code and show us what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: @JuanMendes -- yeah. But user can change from unchecked to checked and submit those changes. How to identify these new checked items? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to handle the click on your own and update the record. However, Ext-JS has already created a column for that. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24760421/227299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rendering your own checkbox, just use a [Check column](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Check) It will update the underlying field when checked.

See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7n0

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields : ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'active'],
    data   : {
        items : [
            { name : 'Lisa',  email : 'lisa@simpsons.com',  phone : '555-111-1224', active : true  },
            { name : 'Bart',  email : 'bart@simpsons.com',  phone : '555-222-1234', active : true  },
            { name : 'Homer', email : 'home@simpsons.com',  phone : '555-222-1244', active : false },
            { name : 'Marge', email : 'marge@simpsons.com', phone : '555-222-1254', active : true  }
        ]
    },
    proxy  : {
        type   : 'memory',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title    : 'Simpsons',
    height   : 200,
    width    : 400,
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    store    : store,
    columns  : [
        { text : 'Name', dataIndex : 'name' },
        { text : 'Email', dataIndex : 'email', flex : 1 },
        { text : 'Phone', dataIndex : 'phone' },
        { xtype : 'checkcolumn', text : 'Active', dataIndex : 'active' }
    ]
});


// Show the modified records
 var recs = store.getRange();
 var data = recs.map(function(o){return o.data;});
 alert(Ext.encode(data));
```

Comment: Yeah. This is working fine. Thank you. But is there any way to get the data that exists before modification, so that i can compare both old and new data and then update only changes. Thanks.

Comment: @ravikanth See http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-snapshot for a list of the records before they were changed. Better yet, to get a list of modified records, use http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getModifiedRecords